# How to know the ModuleID (in % format) of current project in SBT?

Tags: sbt

Say, I have a SBT project and what to know its ModuleID (with `%` and `%%`) so I can add it to `libraryDependencies`. How to query SBT for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setting `projectID` provides the `ModuleID`.  Reference another project's `projectId` by scoping it appropriately, such as `(projectID in otherProject).value`.

Comment: Whoa! What a clever approach! Since `otherProject` can be a `ProjectRef` or `RootProject` I can reference any SBT-managed project! Thanks so much.